# Working on using Keras VGG16 -- Trouble output shapes

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to train the VGG16 model (from keras.applications) from scratch and I get a weird error

X_train shape is (73257, 48, 48, 3)

Y_train shape is (73257, 10)

I have no idea what's going on... I assume it has to do with the conv layer before it but since I'm importing the model directly from keras I'm having issues figuring out where I went wrong.

My dataset is comprised of 73,257 images which have (48,48,3) shape. I am essentially trying to do character recognition (think mnist flavor) but I am getting hung up on feeding this through the model (with weights set to 0).

```
model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False,
                                       weights=None,
                                       input_shape=(48, 48, 3),
                                       input_tensor=None, pooling='avg', classes=10)
sgd = SGD(lr=.1)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print('X_train shape is {}'.format(X_train.shape))
print('Y_train shape is {}'.format(y_train.shape))

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

This is the error I am getting

> File "/home/codebrotherone/PycharmProjects/Computer Vision/deep_neural/dnn.py", line 169, in VGG16
>       batch_size=128)
>
> File "/home/codebrotherone/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1574, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)
>
> File "/home/codebrotherone/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1411, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='target')
>
> File "/home/codebrotherone/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 141, in _standardize_input_data
>       str(array.shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (73257, 10)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, for classification problems, you should have `include_top=True` and `classes=10`.

This is enough. Since you're not including top, and are using a global pooling, you should end up with something like (73257,512). But the message you're getting suggests that you have not used the pooling in this attempt. Something is not quite matching.

Anyway, go with this:

```
model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=True,
                                   input_shape=(48, 48, 3),
                                   classes=10)
```

Comment: awesome thanks for your response.. but I want to set the weights = None, and when I try running it just hovers around 0.0000E10 for accuracy... what are some ways to determine batch size? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Comment: I just tried batch_size = 100, 20 epochs (still running) and my accuracy is going down while my loss starts at -788 then goes to nan...

Comment: Ok, you can add `weights=None`, no problem. Nan may be due to math errors (division by zero, for instance) and other things I don't understand very well. Your batch size should be one that fits your memory and processing time. (Keep testing for the best performances). --- I think "relu" may be a cause of Nan if all its inputs are lower than zero. That might be solved by initializing the weights all positive. --- Also notice that there is a `preprocess_input` function to be imported from the vgg16 module in order to fit the caffe image format.